# Send file using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, form-data

I'm having this problem when I try to send a file using Node.js.

I have an endpoint that receives the file, upload the file to S3 (this works fine), but also we need to send that file (not the S3 URL) to another API and here is where the error comes. This is my code:

```js
const { file } = data;
let buffer = Buffer.from(file.data, 'base64');
let base64File = buffer.toString();
let form = new FormData();

form.append('file', base64File);
const apiUrl = 'someapiurl';

const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  body: form
});
return await response.json();
```

The API that I need to use, receives the file as base64 format, but every time that I send the file, it says that the format is not correct.

We are not storing files in the server right now, we save them in the S3 bucket and that file is being send from a React application.